# Properly defining dimens.xml to support both Android mobile and tablet devices

Tags: android, xml, mobile, tablet, dimension

I have an app in the play store which runs on all mobiles and now I want to release it on tablets as well.

1) The images have been designed for xhdpi screens. So I think that will be sufficient to support tablets as well or should I redesign the images seperately for tablets?

2) I want to split dimens.xml into 3 categories -

- dimens.xml for all mobile phones
- dimens.xml for all 7 inch tablets
- dimens.xml for all 10 inch tablets

The solution I came up with is divide the values folder like below -

- values/dimens.xml
- values-sw620dp/dimens.xml
- values-sw720dp/dimens.xml

but since few mobile phones might fall into values-sw620dp/dimens.xml or values-sw720dp/dimens.xml, What is the appropriate way to divide dimens.xml into 3 categories??

Please do not post the below picture as I want to divide into 3 categories
Following is Struture Answered by Many

[image: Struture Answered by Many]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) There is no tablet device in the market with higher density than xhdpi. Therefore, xhdpi images are sufficient to support tablets

2) Dividing the values folder as below will be helpful

> ```
>     - values\dimens.xml
>     - values-land\dimens.xml
>     - values-sw600dp\dimens.xml
>     - values-sw600dp-land\dimens.xml
>     - values-sw720dp\dimens.xml
>     - values-sw720dp-land\dimens.xml
> ```

The suffix -land is used for lanscape orientation.

Mobile phones do not fall into the sw600dp or sw720dp category. I think you are confused between dp and px.

**Example:**

Take Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge.

Resolution : 1440 x 2560px

Density    : xxxhdpi

Converting 1440px to dp at xxxhdpi density, you get 320dp   ([Convert px to dp](https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/))

Therfore the width of Samsung Galaxy S7 edge in dp is 320dp and will fall in values\dimens.xml file

If you take a Tab and find dp similarly, you will notice that the dp will be greater than or equal to 600dp.